# How to pass c function pointer in swift

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, callback

I'm using a C third-part library in my swift project that how to pass a callback function pointer in swift?
When I call third-part function "register", I get an error "Can not invoke......."

thanks for helping about this issue

```
// file: MyClass.swift
 class MyClass: Object {

   init() {
       typealias callbackPtr = CFunctionPointer<((CInt , UnsafePointer<Void>) -> Void)>
       let selfObject = unsafeBitCast(self, UnsafePointer<Void>.self)

       // call third-part function
       register(callbackPtr, selfObject) //failure point is here
   }

   func greeting() {
       println(“Hello…”)
   }    

}

// file: callBack.h
//
// Third-part Function
// register(void(*functionPtr)(number int, void *context) handler, void *context)
//
// Third-party callback function pointer
// typedef void (*functionPtr)(number int, void *context);

void callbackFunctionPointer(number int, void *context)

// file: callBack.m
void callbackFunctionPointer(number int, void *context) {

    MyClass *myClass =  (__bridge MyClass *)context;
   [myClass greeting];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `register(&callbackPtr, selfObject)` to pass the pointer instead of the variable. The `&` gets the pointer of the variable (or pointer).

Comment: get an error, If I add & in register function -> Error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context register(&callbackPtr, selfObject)

Comment: Can you please edit with the method declaration as well as the actual error message?

Comment: The call back function format is defined in third-part library. I can just flowing

Comment: I'm looking for the register function in the header, not random typedef statements :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78623/discussion-between-schemetrical-and-cocoauser).